# Numeric Data type SQL

Tags: sql, numeric

i want to add a new column to an existing table. I want to have a numeric data type and the default value of the column must be zero. So here is what i am trying.

```
ALTER TABLE COUNTRY
ADD MOBILE_ACTIVE NUMERIC(1,0) NOT NULL
```

and i am getting the following error

ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT definition specified, or the column being added is an identity or timestamp column, or alternatively if none of the previous conditions are satisfied the table must be empty to allow addition of this column. Column 'MOBILE_ACTIVE' cannot be added to non-empty table 'COUNTRY' because it does not satisfy these conditions.

Comment: ALTER TABLE COUNTRY
ADD MOBILE_ACTIVE NUMERIC(1,0) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14535517/sergey) suggested in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72898283/numeric-data-type-sql#comment128757372_72898283) You should add `default` as in the error:

```sql
ALTER TABLE COUNTRY
ADD MOBILE_ACTIVE NUMERIC(1,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Or you should allow `null` as `null` is a *non-value* while `0` is a value of 0, so if you want it should have a value you should `default` it to 0, and if not you should allow `null`.

For dates you **should** use `null`, but for `text` and `int` some say never use `null`.

But one thing to note is, that by using `default` you add a `constraint` which will not allow you to `drop` the column without dropping the constraint (at least in SQL Server which I use, don't know about other), so you should add a `constraint` name, if you would want to be able to drop it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a not null column, in a table that already has data.

You will need to run

```
ALTER TABLE COUNTRY
ADD MOBILE_ACTIVE NUMERIC(1,0) NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT DF_MOBILE_ACTIVE DEFAULT 0 --create DEFAULT CONSTRANTI
WITH VALUES --must be used to populate the col for the existing rows
```

another note... why use `numeric(1,0)`? it just means you get a one-digit number
The proper data type for a true/false value is `bit`, and if you need a small integer there are fitting [data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) like `tinyint`